# Codeigniter Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a problem, when I wanted to upload content on the server, an **error** message like this.

> Object of class **CI_DB_mysqli_result** could not be converted to string

I use **CodeIgniter** and a stored procedure. The following code in my model:

```
function inputBerita($data){
    $idBerita = $this->db->query("select BeritaGenIdFunc('kodebaru')");
    $this->db->query("call BeritaAddPro('$idBerita',?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $data);
    return;
}
```

error in line:

```
$this->db->query("call BeritaAddPro('$idBerita',?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $data);
```

How do I solve the problem? Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
function inputBerita($data){
    $idBerita = $this->db->query("select BeritaGenIdFunc('kodebaru')");
    $row = $idBerita->row();
    $query=$this->db->query("call BeritaAddPro('$row->name',?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $data);
    return $query->result();
}
```